# Leaflet: Access KML folder name

Tags: leaflet, kml, json

I have a leaflet map and a `kml` file. I load the kml file using the plugin: [leaflet-omnivore](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore). Now I want to access the `<folder> <name>`(which is "RegionName"). I need it because I want to link the `kml` with an other `json` file which also has `RegionName` as a `properties.name`. But when output the loaded kml file via `console.log(myKML)` I can only access the `<name>` below `<placemark>`

The code I load the kml with:

```
var myKML = omnivore.kml('KML/Testdaten_KML.kml', null, L.mapbox.featureLayer());
```

The kml file is structured like:

```
<Folder>
  <name>RegionName</name>
  <Placemark>
    <name>Form 1</name>
    <Polygon>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <tessellate>1</tessellate>
          <coordinates>
            11.82,52.60
            11.86,52.58
            11.90,52.61
            11.87,52.62
            11.82,52.60
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
  </Placemark>
</Folder>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is one possible solution, it is a bit long but straightforward!

**Step 1:** Create a global variable ("kmlJSON") and load your KML via a JQUERY AJAX call (or [vanilla JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery), as you prefer):

```
var kmlJSON;
var url = 'KML/Testdaten_KML.kml'

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {},
    success: function(data){
        kmlJSON=xmlToJson(data);
    },
    dataType: 'xml',
    error: function (request,status,error) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
    }
});
```

**Step 2:** Enter this function ('xmlToJson') as is, taken from [here](https://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json):

```
function xmlToJson(xml) {

    // Create the return object
    var obj = {};

    if (xml.nodeType == 1) { // element
        // do attributes
        if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
        obj["@attributes"] = {};
            for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
                var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
                obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
            }
        }
    } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) { // text
        obj = xml.nodeValue;
    }

    // do children
    if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
        for(var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
            var nodeName = item.nodeName;
            if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
            } else {
                if (typeof(obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
                    var old = obj[nodeName];
                    obj[nodeName] = [];
                    obj[nodeName].push(old);
                }
                obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
};
```

**Step 3:** You can then access the KML as a JSON. Normally, it should be:

```
kmlJSON.kml.Document.Folder.name
```

but assuming the KML snippet you attached is the whole KML then it should just be:

```
kmlJSON.Folder.name
```

Comment: hm, my `var kmlJSON` ends up beind `"undefined"`

Comment: That most likely means the ajax call didn't succeed, is the relative path (`var url`) to your data ('KML\Testdaten_KML.kml) correct? Try an absolute path, see here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Comment: yes, I was trying to access the `var kmlJSON` before the ajax call succeeded. Fixed it  now and worked

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question!

My line of reasoning:

1. omnivore.kml does two things

   - loads the kml file over http
   - parses the kml file and generates geoJSON
2. omnivore does not extract the tag you want
3. Therefore, what I would do is:
   3.1 load the kml separately 
   3.2 parse the kml file manually to extract the data you need
   3.3 use omnivore.kml.parse to parse the akctual kml

3.1 Should any web-developer be able to perform using some library

3.2 can be done using something like this

```
var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString, 'text/xml')
var name xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('folder')[0].getElementsByTagName('name')[0].innerHTML;
```

3.3 is just a matter of using  omnivore.kml.parse